On closed subspaces whose image by a continuous linear operator isn't a closed subspace
In this question, it's proved that, if $T:X\to Y$ is a continuous linear operator between Banach spaces such that $\ker(T)$ and $T(X)$ have infinite dimension, then there is a closed subspace $W$ of $X$ satisfying $T(W)$ isn't closed.
My question is related to the result above. In the same setting, is there always (or at least in some cases) a closed subspace $W$ such that $T(W)$ isn't closed and, if $Z$ is a closed subspace of $Y$ contained in $T(W)$, then $Z$ is finite-dimensional?
Of course, if $T(W)$ has an enumerable dimension, follows trivially that there is no infinite-dimensional closed subspace.

If you’re just asking for the existence, then you basically already answered your own question. Just let $W$ be a finite dimensional subspace of $X$ (or, if you want it infinite-dimensional, take $W$ to be $\mathrm{ker}(T)$ plus a finite-dimensional space).

@DavidGao thanks for the answer. The question was wrongly formulated. I wanted a stronger version of the original problem. $T(W)$ isn't closed and also that the closed subspaces of $T(W)$ are only the trivial ones. I totally forgot that $T(W)$ could be finite-dimensional. I corrected the text now.

(I’m assuming, by $Z$ is a closed subspace of $T(W)$, you actually meant $Z$ is a closed subspace of $Y$ that is contained in $T(W)$. Otherwise, $Z = T(W)$ would be closed in itself.)
I’m not that familiar with the general theory of Banach spaces, so while I find it likely the answer is yes in general, I’m unable to find a proof. The following, however, is a partial answer showing that the answer is yes whenever $X$ is a Hilbert space.
Since $\mathrm{ker}(T)$ and $T(X)$ are both infinite-dimensional, we may write $X = l^2 \oplus l^2$ where the first direct summand is $\mathrm{ker}(T)$. (If $X$ is non-separable, pick a separable infinite-dimensional subspace of $\mathrm{ker}(T)$ and a separable infinite-dimensional subspace of $\mathrm{ker}(T)^\perp$. Then restrict $T$ to the direct sum of those separable subspaces.) Then $T = \tilde{T} \circ P$ where $\tilde{T}$ is the restriction of $T$ to the second direct summand and is injective, and $P: l^2 \oplus l^2 \to l^2$ is the projection onto the second direct summand.
Now, observe that $F = \{f_n = \frac{\sqrt{n^2 - 1}}{n}e_n \oplus \frac{1}{n}e_n\}$ is an orthonormal sequence in $X$. Let $W = \overline{\mathrm{span}}(F)$. Then $F = \{f_n\}_n$ is an orthonormal basis of $W$ and $P(f_n) = \frac{1}{n}e_n$. Hence, $P|_W$ is injective and compact, and so is $T|_W = \tilde{T} \circ P|_W$. Since $T|_W$ is injective and $W$ is infinite-dimensional, $T(W)$ is infinite-dimensional as well. Therefore, $T(W)$ is not closed in $Y$ as otherwise $T|_W$ would be a bijective compact operator onto an infinite-dimensional Banach space. Furthermore, any infinite-dimensional $Z \subset T(W)$ is not closed in $Y$ either, for effectively the same reason - $T|_{T|_W^{-1}(Z)}$ would otherwise be a bijective compact operator onto the infinite-dimensional Banach space $Z$.

I would assume the general case can be proved similarly - find a closed infinite-dimensional subspace $W$ such that $W \cap \mathrm{ker}(T) = {0}$ and $T|_W$ is compact.

Thanks for the answer @DavidGao. It's a very clever construction and really seems to be generalizable. Just a question for clarification: how can I prove that $P|W$ is compact?

@Emerick ${f_n}_n$ is an orthonormal basis for $W$ and ${e_n}_n$ is an orthonormal sequence in the codomain. $P(f_n) = \frac{1}{n}e_n$ and $\frac{1}{n} \to 0$, so $P|_W$ is compact. (If you haven’t seen this before, the easiest way I could think of to prove this is to show $P|_W$ is the uniform limit of a sequence of finite rank operators. Indeed, define $P_N: W \to l^2$ by $P_N(f_n) = \frac{1}{n}e_n$ when $n < N$ and $P_N(f_n) = 0$ when $n \geq N$. Then $P_N$ is of finite rank and $|P|_W - P_N| = \frac{1}{N} \to 0$.)
